# Google Analytics Reporting API filters/segements

Tags: filter, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use the Google Analytics Core Reporting API and have the following troubles. I know how to fetch that I want the problem I have is:

- I want to use a filter only for specific metrics and not for all of them.
- Is this even possible?

Here is an example how my Reporting "Code" looks like:

```
Metrics "ga:sessions
         ga:goal6Completions
         ga:goal7Completions
         ga:goal10Completions
         ga:totalEvents
         ga:uniqueEvents"

Dimensions "ga:date"

Filters "ga:eventCategory==customerType"
```

I have the same problems with segments as with the filters that all metrics all segmented/filtered and only specific metrics should.

Comment: The filter or segment applies to the whole request. If you like the information without the filter or segment you could make a second request without the filters and merge the results together. In essence you would have the numerator and the denominator of the metrics. https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-07-27&end-date=2015-07-31&metrics=ga%3Asessions%2Cga%3Agoal6Completions%2Cga%3Agoal7Completions%2Cga%3Agoal10Completions%2Cga%3AtotalEvents%2Cga%3AuniqueEvents&dimensions=ga%3Adate&filters=ga%3AeventCategory%3D%3DcustomerType

Comment: Hello Matt,
thanks for your response. Thats currently also the method I use, but I thought there may be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't another way other to get the data you want without creating a new request where the filter isn't applied unfortunately.

Just remember that you are only allowed five requests total. To give context, this may only apply to how I use the Reporting API, but I use Google App Script to push data to Google Sheets.

This may or may not be helpful to you, but the reporting code I use I have made available in a repo on GitHub: https://github.com/jessfeliciano/aggregateGoogleAnalyticsReporting/blob/master/objectQueryWithFilter.js

I've included a guide that gives additional information regarding creating requests in general, so it may spark other ways to go about creating your data trees. I hope this helps.